# Como ocultar una contraseña con * en Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, consola, contraseña, ant

Estamos trabajando en proyecto con java with ant pero al momento de ingresar el usuario y la contraseña correcta que permita seguir con la ejecucion necesitamos que la contraseña aparezca con *, en consola por favor.

Comment: Usa [JPasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html).

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

debes usar el componete JPassword, funciona igual a un JTextField pero su retorno es distinto, no debes recuperar los datos con gettext sino getpassword.

Comment: el componente Password no existe en la libreria estandard, y con TextField te refieres a java.awt.TextField?

Comment: los JtextField y JPassword pertenecen a la libreria swing

Comment: entonces deberias de cambiar donde dice Password por JPassword y donde dice TextField por JTextField